# After installing Node.js in windows 10. command prompt give " npm install -g @angulur/cli " getting errors.how to resolve

Tags: node.js

```
C:\Users\320>npm install -g @angulur/cli
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angulur%2fcli - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@angulur/cli@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can only contain URL-friendly characters
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\320\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-27T17_49_19_624Z-debug.log
```

Comment: That's not how you spell Angular.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave Newton mentionned, you mispelled `Angular` by calling it `Angulur`. 
As it's not existant, NPM returns a 404